# Double to Int Rounding, Logic Issue

Tags: logic

This is more of a puzzle/logic type question, and less of a programming question -- but I was hoping someone could help, because I'm stumped.

I start off with an integer number and need to take X percent of it. Once I get that double number I need to round it back to an integer (Call this Y). It doesn't actually matter if I round it, and I don't really care which way it goes (up or down), so using floor/ceiling would be an acceptable solution -- I just need an int.

Later in the system I will be presented with the int Y, and will need to know what the original number was. At this point if i know what the percentage was, and I know what method i used to get the double to an int -- How can i determine the original number.

This needs to work for every original-number/percentage combination.

Example:

```
Original number: 997
Percentage: 90
Int-Conversion Method: Floor

997 * .90 = 897.3
floor(897.3) = 897
Y = 897
```

..
..
Given 897, and knowing the percentage and int-conversion method, how can I determine the original number was 997?

Comment: `897/.90=996.667` Wasn't the original number 997 not 1000? Obviously it won't be 100% accurate since you rounded `Y`.

Comment: Yes, 997. Sorry I edited the original question. That's the problem/question though, is there a way I can make it 100% accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
997 * .90 = 897.3
floor(897.3) = 897
Y = 897
```

Given the method you have suggested, I will explain why returning to the exact number is not possible, given the method and the data you've provided.

Computing the percentage is fine, and you're left with the `double` value. You then, effectively, truncate some of the data, using the `floor` function. Truncation is not a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), so you can't go back from the 897 -> 897.3, so reproducing the original number is not possible with any degree of certainty. You won't be far wrong, given the scale of the data you've provided, but for larger values, or for situations that require more precision you might find this method to much like guess work.

Comment: Just to confirm, as I think you're saying and I understand. There is no way to do this (using any truncating function / round/floor/ceiling/custom).

Comment: Yup. And with the data you've got I don't see how you could make it 100% accurate. Bit given my response does answer your question, mark it as correct please :)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the formula

```
original number = calculated number / percentage
```

Using your numbers

```
997 = 897 / 0.90
```

In the original calculation and the reverse calculation, you need to round the answer.

If you don't, you'll be off by one more often when you do the reverse calculation.

Comment: I've tried this and there's always edge cases that do not work.

Comment: Fixed my answer.  You'll have to save the double somewhere if you want to be able to reverse the process.